# Python interpreting equal values as non-equal

Tags: python

For this part of the code, which is inside a **for** loop

```
s = 'cl_num = %d, prev_cl_num = %d\n' % (cl_num, prev_cl_num);
fd.write( s );
if cl_num != prev_cl_num:
    bb.instructions[i].is_cache_miss = 1;
    s = 'instruction %x is cache miss, cl_num = %d, prev_cl_num = %d, base_cache_line = %d\n' % (bb.instructions[i].address, cl_num, prev_cl_num, base_cache_line);
    fd.write( s );
    bb.instructions[i].cache_line = cl_num - base_cache_line;
    prev_cl_num = cl_num;
```

I get an output, as this in the fd file,

```
cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557
instruction 400558 is cache miss, cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557, base_cache_line = 65557
cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557
instruction 400560 is cache miss, cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557, base_cache_line = 65557
cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557
instruction 400568 is cache miss, cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557, base_cache_line = 65557
cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557
instruction 400570 is cache miss, cl_num = 65557, prev_cl_num = 65557, base_cache_line = 65557
```

You see, the condition `cl_num != prev_cl_num` gets evaluated to `true` even when `cl_num` is equal to `prev_cl_num`. Why so?

Comment: Where is the loop in your code?

Comment: Loop is over this code

Comment: What does the loop modify? `i`? `cl_num`? What types are the values you are displaying? There's not enough information to identify the problem.

Comment: @chepner: Well, the output suggests that the integer value of the two numbers is equal, yet the `instruction` text is also written, which only happens when the two numbers were supposed to be equal. The problem is that `%d` only writes *integral numbers*; a float would be truncated to an integer, yet the equality test could easily fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have floating point values, but only write the integer portion to your file:

```
>>> '%d' % 3.3
'3'
```

Note how the `.3` decimal portion has been ignored; `%d` calls `int()` on the interpolated value.

When writing debugging values, always use `repr()`, or `%r` in formatting:

```
s = 'cl_num = %r, prev_cl_num = %r\n' % (cl_num, prev_cl_num);
```

`repr()` on float values formats them as if using a `%17g` formatter; 17 decimals are shown, scientific notation is used when the exponent is 17 or up.

Comment: Could be, how can you get the type of the value in python?

Comment: @MetallicPriest, as simple as `type(somevariable)`

Comment: @MetallicPriest: You can use `type()` to get the type object, but for the most part `repr()` should make it obvious what type of value you have.